# Handling empty integers

Tags: postgresql

I have this situation where an application some times is passing empty values to an integer parameter, thus getting `syntax error at or near ','`.

Is there a way, from the stored procedure side to handle this?.

An easy way to reproduce this, is for example doing this:

```
select (''::integer);
```

This obviously returns:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
```

That is more or less the same error the stored procedure is returning in the sample case.

P.S.: the server is PostgreSql 9.5.

Comment: Shouldn't the application handle this? An empty string is not an integer.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have access to the source code of the app.

Comment: I get a different error: `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
LINE 1: SELECT (''::int) AS the_int` Did you run the same fragment?

Comment: Post the function code.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`nullif().`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF)

```
with the_data(str) as (
values 
    ('1'), 
    ('2'), 
    ('')
)

select nullif(str, '')::integer as value
from the_data;

  value 
--------
      1
      2
 <null>    
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Mm, no, the problem is params are empty, not null, not ''.

Comment: Lack of an argument always will raise a syntax error, you have to correct this in the client app.

Comment: Yes, kind of difficult for quite an old app.